# How to convert object to associated array?

Tags: javascript, object, converters

I have javascript object like as

```
var obj = {
    param1 : {
        subParam1: 10,
        subParam2: 20
    },
    param2: 123
}
```

if need to convert it to object with keys only in root

```
obj = {
    'param1.subParam1' : 10,
    'param1.subParam2' : 20,
    'param2' : 123
}
```

Comment: And [if you want to go the other way...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236014/712294).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple recursive function for this:

```
function flatten(obj) {

    var result = {},
        temp, key, subkey;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) == '[object Object]') {
                temp = flatten(obj[key]);
                for (subkey in temp) {
                    result[key + '.' + subkey] = temp[subkey];
                }
            }
            else result[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Looks like it works as expected:

```
{param1.subParam1: 10, param1.subParam2: 20, param2: 123}
```

Comment: +1 for a working answer http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/3513LLup/

Answer (score 1):

Some might call this dense, some might call it compact, some might call in obscure, some might call it elegant.

```
function flatten_object_into_dot_notation(obj) {

    return function _flatten(obj, prefix, result) {

        return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(_, key) {
            var val = obj[key];
            key = prefix + key;

            if (val && typeof val==='object') { _flatten(val, key + '.', result); } 
            else { result[key] = val; }

            return result;
        }, result);

    }(obj, '', {});

}
```